# Cannot sign into my app using AzreADB2C. Getting browser error: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-edge, azure-authentication

I am currently writing an app in ASP.Net Core 3.1. Everything has been working fine on localhost (IIS Express) for weeks, but all of a sudden, my authentication has stopped working.

I am using AzureADB2C for authentication. Whenever my app needs to redirect to the login page, I get the following error in Edge/Chrome.

```
Hmmm… can't reach this page
It looks like the webpage at https://localhost:44344/ might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

The browser also displays a warning telling me that the `Connection to this site isn't secure`

When I use the Azure Portal to test my user flow, I can see that Azure is redirecting me back to `https://localhost:44344/AzureADB2C/Account/Error#id_token=eyJ0{snip}`. The token actually seems to be valid, but I am not sure why Azure is redirecting to an error page.

Here are my Azure Ad B2C settings

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://MY_COMPANY_NAME.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "MY_COMPANY_NAME.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": ""
  },
```

Everything was working perfectly fine this morning. After restarting my PC, I launched Visual Studio, and my app would no longer work. I tested my app on another PC, and got the same errors.

UPDATE: After testing my user flow in the Azure Portal, with my local app not running, it looks like Azure is correctly redirecting back to https://localhost:44344/signin-oidc#id_token={token}. So the redirect to the error page is happening within the auth middleware. No errors are written to the output window, so I have no idea what is going wrong.

I tried rolling back my app to a previous commit from a week ago, but I am still seeing the same issue with older code that used to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Windows. I recently updated to Insider Build `19587.rs_prerelease.200313-1639` and that's when the issue started occurring. After rolling back to `19582.rs_prerelease.200306-1640`, my app authentication started to work again.

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.^_^

Comment: I have to wait 9 more hours before I mark my response as the answer.
This issue was also reported by another user in the Visual Studio Developer Community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/957518/err-http2-protocol-error-in-aspnet-core-web-app-wi.html